# Scala : Match particular word and count frequency

Tags: scala

**Input**

> List((0,List()),(1,List()))
>
> List((0,List()),(1,List("ABC")))

**Output**
Only give count for List() from above text

**Count**

```
2
1
```

Comment: please post what have you tried!

Comment: Input: List(1,2), code: ?, Output: profit.
If this is a question, I want to be rich :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each list:

```
val count = list.count { case (_, l) => l.isEmpty }
```